# How to know if a file input is not empty with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hi I am trying to validate if a file input is not empty so I am doing this:

My HTML code:

```
<input accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" type="file" class="form-control" v-on:change="onFileChange">
```

I am doing the validation in the button:

```
<button 
     :disabled="I need to know what it'll be here ? !isDisabled : isDisabled"
     type="submit"
     class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split">
      <span class="icon text-white-50">
         <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </span>
     <span class="text">Guardar</span>
</button>
```

But I do not know how to do that because it does not have v-model and I do not know how to check if it's empty. How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<div id="app">
    <input type="file" @change="fileChange">
    <button :disabled="noFiles">Submit</button>
</div>
```

[**With the Composition API**](https://jsfiddle.net/1f9s7ohq/1/)

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

createApp({
    setup() {
        const noFiles = ref(true);
        const fileChange = (e) => noFiles.value = !e.target.files.length;

        return { noFiles, fileChange };
    },
}).mount('#app');
```

[**Without the Composition API**](https://jsfiddle.net/bgpnq1x3/)

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    
    data: () => ({
        noFiles: true,
    }),

    methods: {
        fileChange(event) {
            this.noFiles = !event.target.files.length;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
data(){
   return{
      file: null,
   }
}

methods: {
   onFileChange(){
      this.file = event.target.files[0];
   }, 
}
```

and check in button submit method:

```
if(this.file !== null){
   //some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ref` to the file input then inside the submit handler check `this.$refs.file.files` length :

```
 <input accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" ref="file"
    type="file" class="form-control" v-on:change="onFileChange">
```

```
  save(){
      console.log(this.$refs.file.files.length)
    }
```

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cesfz483/)**

Comment: Hi but when I use that it says [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined" :/ what could it be? I added ref="file" and I added this this.$refs.file.files.length to the submit button :disabled

Comment: are you using composition api?

Comment: i mean `setup` like in @MattDeacalion answer

Comment: No I am not using setup I just do this in a method onFileChange(e){
                console.log(e.target.files[0]);
                this.file = e.target.files[0];
            }, My thing is how I can add the validation disabled in the button

Comment: I did what you put but it says that it's undefined

Comment: the code provided doesn't work please config the vue in that fiddle, you just copied/pasted the code snippets